# How can I create a rolling mean for each user based on previous 7 days of activity?

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, time-series, rolling-computation

I've been looking at past posts and can't seem to find something that matches my needs. 
Goal: For each user, I want a mean of their previous 7 days of activities (not counting the current observation). Some people will have no activities during that window (which is OK), others will have a lot.

I've been using dplyr to group by user, but can't figure out how to take each time stamp and capture the mean of all activities before that time stamp to get a rolling mean for each person. This is a large dataset so it needs to be efficient. I'm sure datatable can accomplish this, but I find the code difficult to interpret even though it's much faster.

```
User  Stamp          activity   Score    

1     2019-06-20     "Car"      4500
1     2019-06-18     "Car"      600
1     2019-06-15     "Walk"     650
1     2019-06-21     "Ride"     790
2     2019-06-21     "Car"      800    
2     2019-06-23     "Car"      500
3     2019-06-11     "Walk"     900
4     2019-06-15     "Walk"     200   
4     2019-06-12     "Walk"     900
```

Needs to become something like this. We have rolling proportions and rolling means for each user based on the time stamp, excluding that timestamps observation.

```
User  Stamp          activity   Score   proportion_walk   mean_score    

1     2019-06-20     "Car"      4500    .5                 625
1     2019-06-18     "Car"      600     1                  650
1     2019-06-15     "Walk"     650     0                   0
1     2019-06-21     "Ride"     790     .33                   1916.33
2     2019-06-21     "Car"      800     0                   0
2     2019-06-23     "Car"      500     0                   800
3     2019-06-11     "Walk"     900     0                   0
4     2019-06-15     "Walk"     200     1                   900
4     2019-06-12     "Walk"     900     1                   900
```

Comment: What is rolling proportion?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck probably something like `mean(activity == "Walk")` for the previous 7 days, although the shown, desired output values don't really match to that.

Comment: @jgig101 I'm not sure if you are interested in a `data.table` solution or not, but the correct tag would have the dot in the middle. Otherwise, maybe add the `dplyr` tag instead.

Comment: This is all very helpful, a rolling proportion would be, for example, the total proportion of "Walk" in all activities up until that date for each user. So here, user 1's second activity should be proportion of 1 since the first activity was a walk. See I made an error I'll correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try:

```
library(data.table)

df <- setDT(df)[, Stamp := as.Date(Stamp)][
  , `:=` (mean_score = sapply(Stamp, 
                              function(x) 
                                mean(Score[between(Stamp, x - 7, x - 1)])
  ),
  proportion_walk = sapply(Stamp, 
                           function(x) 
                             round(mean(
                               activity[between(Stamp, x - 7, x - 1)] == 'Walk'
                               ),2)
  )
  ), by = User][
    is.nan(mean_score), `:=` (mean_score = 0, proportion_walk = 0)]
```

Output:

```
   User      Stamp activity Score mean_score proportion_walk
1:    1 2019-06-20      Car  4500    625.000            0.50
2:    1 2019-06-18      Car   600    650.000            1.00
3:    1 2019-06-15     Walk   650      0.000            0.00
4:    1 2019-06-21     Ride   790   1916.667            0.33
5:    2 2019-06-21      Car   800      0.000            0.00
6:    2 2019-06-23      Car   500    800.000            0.00
7:    3 2019-06-11     Walk   900      0.000            0.00
8:    4 2019-06-15     Walk   200    900.000            1.00
9:    4 2019-06-12     Walk   900      0.000            0.00
```

For `proportion_walk`, I believe there's a typo in your output based on your description. Otherwise please rephrase; for instance, `2019-06-20` cannot have 0.33 as there are 2 days behind and one of them is `Walk`.

Comment: This is fantastic. Is there a way to do this by hour? So let's say User 1 has two activities on the same day but one activity is an hour before.

Comment: Also, is there a way to get a total count of the User in that same window? Thank you so much!

Comment: By hour, you'd need to convert it to `POSIXct` and instead of days in `x-7, x-1` put hours in seconds, e.g. if checking for previous 7 hours this would be `7 * 3600`, etc. You'd get total count of the user by replacing `mean` with `length`, if you mean by count the number of user occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data in the Note at the end perform a left self join on the indicated criteria taking the average of `Score` for all matching rows or 0 if none.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, 
         coalesce(avg(b.Activity == 'Walk'), 0) as Proportion_Walk, 
         coalesce(avg(b.Score), 0) as Mean
  from DF as a 
  left join DF as b on a.User = b.User and 
                       b.Stamp < a.Stamp and b.Stamp >= a.Stamp - 7
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  User      Stamp activity Score Proportion_Walk     Mean
1    1 2019-06-20      Car  4500       0.5000000  625.000
2    1 2019-06-18      Car   600       1.0000000  650.000
3    1 2019-06-15     Walk   650       0.0000000    0.000
4    1 2019-06-21     Ride   790       0.3333333 1916.667
5    2 2019-06-21      Car   800       0.0000000    0.000
6    2 2019-06-23      Car   500       0.0000000  800.000
7    3 2019-06-11     Walk   900       0.0000000    0.000
8    4 2019-06-15     Walk   200       1.0000000  900.000
9    4 2019-06-12     Walk   900       0.0000000    0.000
```

### Note

The data in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- 'User  Stamp          activity   Score    
1     2019-06-20     "Car"      4500
1     2019-06-18     "Car"      600
1     2019-06-15     "Walk"     650
1     2019-06-21     "Ride"     790
2     2019-06-21     "Car"      800    
2     2019-06-23     "Car"      500
3     2019-06-11     "Walk"     900
4     2019-06-15     "Walk"     200   
4     2019-06-12     "Walk"     900'

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$Stamp <- as.Date(DF$Stamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library("dplyr")
library("purr")
DF %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(mean_score = map_dbl(Stamp, 
                              ~mean(Score[(Stamp > . - 7) & (Stamp < .)]))) %>%
  mutate(mean_score =ifelse(is.nan(mean_score), 0, mean_score))
```

### Output

```
  User Stamp      activity Score mean_score
  <int> <date>     <fct>    <int>      <dbl>
1     1 2019-06-20 Car       4500       625 
2     1 2019-06-18 Car        600       650 
3     1 2019-06-15 Walk       650         0 
4     1 2019-06-21 Ride       790      1917.
5     2 2019-06-21 Car        800         0 
6     2 2019-06-23 Car        500       800 
7     3 2019-06-11 Walk       900         0 
8     4 2019-06-15 Walk       200       900 
9     4 2019-06-12 Walk       900         0
```

Comment: I asked the similar question few days back and Ronak Shah's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574196/rolling-sum-for-number-of-questions-solved-for-past-7-days-by-every-user