# Lagged rolling interval window in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, window, cumsum

I have a dataset like **df**, where **year_month** represents the year in the first 2 digits, and the month in the last 2 digits (1901=01/2019).

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
year_month <- c(1801,1809,1812,1901,1908, 1901,1909,1912,2011,2012 )
value <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)

df <- data.frame(id, year_month, value)
```

I want to sum the accumulated **value** of each firm during the last year (e.g. if we are in 1901=01/2019, I want to start counting since 1801 (01/2018) and record the history of values prior to 1901, i.e. count from 1801 until 1812). The dataset will look like **one_year_window**

```
value_last_year <- c(NA,10,30,60,90,NA,60,130,80,170)

one_year_window <- data.frame(id, year_month, value, value_last_year)
```

I have tried several ways (cummsum()) in dplyr without success.

Any clue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate a rolling sum in an R data frame based on a date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062114/calculate-a-rolling-sum-in-an-r-data-frame-based-on-a-date-column)

Comment: Not really, as I have a different framework where I have not to count the current month but previous history in the last 11 months (12 months if you start counting in the current month). So what I really need is a LAGGED ROLLING WINDOW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, year = round(year_month, -2)) %>% 
  mutate(value_last_year = cumsum(value)) %>%
  ungroup(year) %>% 
  mutate(value_last_year = ifelse(year == max(year), value, NA)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-year)
```

Though it may be to your advantage to compute the cumulative sum across all years and then filter by `id` and `year_month` if you need their most recent records.

**Output**

```
      id year_month value value_last_year
   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     1       1801    10              NA
 2     1       1809    20              NA
 3     1       1812    30              NA
 4     1       1901    40              40
 5     1       1908    50              50
 6     2       1901    60              NA
 7     2       1909    70              NA
 8     2       1912    80              NA
 9     2       2011    90              90
10     2       2012   100             100
```

---

**Update**

Based on your updated post. I do not take credit for this answer. You should follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062114/calculate-a-rolling-sum-in-an-r-data-frame-based-on-a-date-column) and upvote the answer there that this is based on:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  mutate(yrmd = ymd(paste0(year_month, "01"))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value_last_year = rollapplyr(value, width = 1:n() - findInterval(yrmd %m-% months(13), yrmd), sum),
         value_last_year = ifelse(row_number() == 1, NA, value_last_year - value)) %>% 
  select(-yrmd) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
      id year_month value value_last_year
   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     1       1801    10              NA
 2     1       1809    20              30
 3     1       1812    30              60
 4     1       1901    40              90
 5     1       1908    50             140
 6     2       1901    60              NA
 7     2       1909    70             130
 8     2       1912    80             210
 9     2       2011    90             170
10     2       2012   100             190
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I think you did not get the TIME-WINDOW framework. I want to cumsum() over the last 12 months, not over the current year, so I don't want to group by year

Comment: @vog your logic is not clear to me. If you want a rolling 12-month window then for `id==1` and `year_month==1901` why are the values from `1812`, `1809`, and `1801` not included in the summation since they're within 12 months of `1901`? For the last observation of `one_year_window` how do you get `170`?

Comment: If observation is in 1806 I'll be interested in cumsum() all value from 1706. If observation occurs in 1807 I'll be interested in cumsum() all value from 1707... Therefore, the last observation occurs in 2012 (for id == "2"), then we may take all info available since 1912 happening before 2012 for this id (which is 1912=80 + 2011=90 -> 80+90=170)... I hope its clearer now. Thank you!

Comment: Right, so again why is `value_last_year` in row 7, for example, not 60+70=130? Instead, you have `NA`.

Comment: You are totally right. Now the edit may be clearer. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: I have tried to convert my dataset into a "panel data" like. However I end up with more than 140M rows (which is not very feasible to handle)

Comment: @vog, I've updated this answer using another person's solution as mentioned. If this works for you please upvote that answer and I will mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing I miss is how to not count the present period. That is, Row n.10 may be 170 (start counting 12 months ago and not counting the present month). Same applies to other values

Comment: Row 7 may count only 60, etc Thats why the first value is NA, because you don't take into account the current month. You are interested in the history of values up to this moment. It looks to me that the window you have proposed me should be lagged one month. Is it possible to make this adjustment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232697/discussion-between-vog-and-lmc).

Comment: @vog With a few minor adjustments to the posted link, I've updated the answer to exclude the current month/year. Please see the updated answer.